# Prove that the determinant of an invertible matrix $A$ is equal to $±1$ when all of the entries of $A$ and $A^{−1}$ are integers.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, determinant, alternative-proof

> Prove that the determinant of an invertible matrix $A$ is equal to $±1$ when all of the entries of $A$ and $A^{−1}$ are integers.

I can explain the answer but would like help translating it into a **concise** proof with equations.

My explanation:

The fact that $\det(A) = ±1$ implies that when we perform Gaussian
elimination on $A$, we never have to multiply rows by scalars. This means
that for each column, the pivot entry is created by the previous column’s
row operations and can be brought into place by swapping rows.
(And the first column must already contain a $1$). Therefore, we never need to
multiply by a non-integral value to perform Gaussian elimination.

Comment: That's the converse

Comment: Typesetting: you need to put { } around the -1. Otherwise ^ only puts the immediately following character as a superscript. Many math things like det, sin etc need a backslash in front of them when you are writing inside dollar signs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $A\in\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ such that $A^{-1}\in\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$. Note that the determinant of an integer matrix is an integer, so $\det\colon\mathbb Z^{n\times n}\to \mathbb Z$. Now, $1=\det(\mathbb I)=\det(A\cdot A^{-1})=\det(A)\cdot\det(A^{-1})$. Since both $\det(A)$ and $\det(A^{-1})$ are integers, they can only be $1$ or $-1$.